# View : chain two rotation with different pivots

Tags: android, view

I am trying to apply two different rotations to a view, let's say for example :
1 : 20° pivotX = width/2 pivotY= height/2
2 : 90° pivotX = 0       pivotY= 0

However `View.setPivotX()` & `View.setPivotY()` both seem to only change the values in an unique matrix, so when I change the pivots, it reapply the first rotation with that new pivot, which is not what I want to do.

Is there a way to handle these two rotations in a totally independent way ?

Comment: Different question, but you might find this helpful with regard to pre, post, set and clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246415/clearly-understand-matrix-calculation/13246914#13246914

Comment: @Simon yes, I think that I will have to do something like this.
I can always apply my two rotations from the same pivot and compensate with setTranslationX/Y but I would like to be able to define them separately in order to avoid unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different methods to set both of your rotations'. first is :

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 20f,  width/2, height/2);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(0);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
View.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

and the second one :

```
View.setPivotX(0);
View.setPivotY(0);
View.animate().rotation(90f).setDuration(0);
```